# Irremovable bottom margin in div when using image

Tags: html, css

I am trying too code a simple thing: an image in a div with no space between their borders but somehow I always get a bottom margin (or padding depending on how you want to see it). I tried putting margin and padding to 0 but it doesn't change anything.

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Sandbox</title>
        <style>
            *{margin:0;padding:0;}
            div{
                background:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="image.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried on two browser already (Chrome, Maxthon) no luck. is it in the specification or all web browser are messing when it come to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display your `<img />` as a block-level element:

```
div > img {
    display: block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xsLudk7g/1/)

Answer (score 2):

**The problem and solution:**

The reason is because inline-elements (such as images) align automatically to the baseline of the parent box unless modified by the [vertical-align](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) property. If you ever set a block-level element to display as an `inline-block` you'll often encounter this problem also. To fix this you align the image with the top or bottom of the div as follows:

```
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**Understanding baseline:**

Baseline is easy to understand when thinking about text. Letters such as **abcdefhiklmnorstuvwxz** all sit on the baseline. There is, however, room under this line to handle letters that extend past the baseline. All other letters also sit on the baseline, but there is a portion of the letter that extends below the baseline. These include the letters: **gjpqy**. As inline elements (including images) sit on the baseline by default there will be extra space below them unless you modify the vertical-alignment.